# WPF - different hover cursor if Ctrl key is pressed

Tags: wpf, cursor, mouseover

I want a normal cursor when I mouse over items in a WPF tree, unless the control key is down, in which case I'd like it to be a hand cursor.

How would you suggest I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the `PreviewKeyDown` and `PreviewKeyUp` events for the window and set the `Cursor` property, e.g.:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PreviewKeyDown += (s, e) => 
        {
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        };
        PreviewKeyUp += (s, e) => 
        {
            this.Cursor = null;
        };
 }
```

Comment: Sneaky solution, I like it! Alas, I can't use it. The hand cursor would apply to the entire tree, all tree items and all the area around them that belongs to the tree but not to the items. Additionally, for my scenario, I want only certain tree items to have the hand cursor. I tried to add this handler to the tree item, but the sender in the event handler turns out to be the selected item, rather than the one under the mouse. I didn't expect this to be so tricky.

Comment: You want to explain what a "tree item" is in your case then. Please provide a full but minimal repo of your issue.